# Trying to change the brightness of a LED in Arduino by entering characters in c

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

We are trying to make a program that changes the brightness of a LED connected to our Arduino with keystrokes. The c-serial port communication part is done but we are having some problems with the Arduino part.

```c
int LedPin = 3; 
int brightness = 90; 
char deger; 
void setup () {
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop () {
    if(Serial.available()>0) 
        deger = Serial.read();

    if(deger== 'C') {
        brightness = 0;
        analogWrite (LedPin, brightness);
    }  //to set the brightness to 0 after an error

    if(deger== 'A') {
        if(brightness>=255)
            brightness = 0;
        brightness=brightness+15;   // to increase led brightness by 15 with every entry
        analogWrite (LedPin, brightness);
    }

    if(deger== 'B') {
        if(brightness<=0)
            brightness = 254; 
        brightness=brightness-15;  //to decrease led brightness by 15 with every entry
        analogWrite (LedPin, brightness);
    } 
}
```

We want the brightness to increase when we enter 'A' and decrease when we enter 'B', but what happens is the brightness changes randomly when A is entered and increases by 15 when B is entered. You can see that B acts completely opposite of our intentions an A is random. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: try to make brightness a char instead of an int

Comment: First, move the bounds test *after* the code that adjusts the brightness. Otherwise you'll end up sending values outside 0-255 to analogWrite. I'm not familiar enough with Arduinos to have more specific advice, but this is a generic problem on any system.

Comment: Agreed. In your case if brightness is 250. the condition brigthness>255 will be false, then you will increment brightness by 15 and write this value in the AnalogOutput.

Comment: @Olaf if you edit the tags and remove C (which I agree) you could at least edit the code to specify the language so the code doesn't loose the colors. Also correcting the indentation would have been nice.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Instead of commenting, why don't you just do this? Not that it matters; the tag is not relevant to syntax highlighting, resp. it does not really enhance the quality of the question or the formatting. Let's leave this as a minor task to OP. He should have done this from start.

Comment: @Olaf Tags ARE relevant to syntax highlighting. The language and therefore the highlighting is extrapolated from the tags. If no language tags are used then it has to be manually specified. The code was actually correctly highlighted as C but your edit removed the tag and broke the highlighting. This is why I made the comment... (and it would still be nice if you fix it)

Comment: "The code was actually correctly highlighted as C" - That would have been incorrect, because Arduino is clearly **not** C (which makes specifyint the hightlighting manually problematic, too). Feel free to open a meta to enable proper syntax highlighting for the Arduino tag. Until then: such discussions are nothing for comments.

Answer (score 1):

A major problem with your code is that because you are using `deger` as a global variable, and `loop` is called repeatedly, the increases/decreases to the brightness will be applied every time the loop runs, instead of once only when a keypress is received.

You could remedy this in one of several ways. You could clear `deger` at the end of `loop`. You could also enclose the last 3 `if` statements in brackets based on the first `if` condition so they only get run if a character is read.

However, the most logical is just to make `deger` a local variable declared at the start of 'loop`, since there is no need to make it persist between calls:

```
void loop () {
    char deger = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use **switch** instead of 3 if's.

Second, modify the inner if to :

```
switch(deger)
{
case 'A':
        if(brightness+15>=255)
           {
            brightness = 0;
           }
        brightness=brightness+15;   
        analogWrite (LedPin, brightness);
break;
}
```